# HTML Status 500 Apache error on submit

Tags: php, json, forms, submit

I have a simple PHP file that creates buttons for each of my Diablo 3 characters. It utilizes the JSON data from this site, assigns the name of the hero to the button, and the id of the hero to the id field:

http://us.battle.net/api/d3/profile/raphattack-1736/

What I then attempt to do in my code is to append `hero/` + `id` to the URL in order to navigate the user to the page for the specified hero on a button click. Here is the code:

```
<?php   // json.php
    define("URL", "http://us.battle.net/api/d3/profile/raphattack-1736/");
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents(URL));

    foreach ($data->heroes as $mydata) {
        $test = URL . "hero/" . $mydata->id;
        echo <<<_END
<form method="post" action='$test'><input type="submit" id='$mydata->name' value='$mydata->name'></form>
_END;
    }
?>
```

This works correctly in that each button is created with the correct heroes and their corresponding names. Their ids are also associated with the buttons, and when clicked on, the user will be navigated to the correct url. The issue is that it will always result in an error: `HTTP Status 500 - The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.`

If I simply refresh the page, then it will display the JSON data for that hero, so the url is definitely correct. It just seems that upon first nagivating to the page after a button click, this error is always encountered.

Example URL: http://us.battle.net/api/d3/profile/raphattack-1736/hero/4771127

Comment: What does your server error log say?

Comment: Sorry, unless I am misunderstanding you, the error says `The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request`.

Comment: You've misunderstood. Your server maintains an error log that will give a detailed description of the error. With Apache you'll usually find it in `/etc/httpd/logs`

Comment: I'm using WampServer and looking through `/wamp/logs/` I was able to find `apache_error.log` which does have a list of errors, none of which are related to this error. The last entry was from two hours ago. I have tried to replicate the steps again to see if an error would be logged, but it still is not showing up in `apache_error.log`, so it seems like the error is happening but not being logged for some reason. Really strange that a page refresh will work just fine.

Comment: what do you expect to happen when the submit button is clicked? if you just want to see the json remove `method="post"`